# How to get statistic of a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, statistics

I have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6], [1,9], [1,2,4]]
```

I would like to get list statistics in following format:

```
number of lists with 2 elements : 2
number of lists with 3 elements : 3
number of lists with 4 elements : 1
```

What is the best (most pythonic) way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use a [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for lst in lists:
   d[len(lst)] += 1
```

Comment: @delnan You can if you can use counter instead!

Comment: @delnan -- Yeah, it's one of my standby's -- Although I would like to get more used to using `Counter` as well ...

Comment: @jamylak Counter is nice, but not massively more convenient, and far more specialized. My current code base has a dozen good uses for `defaultdict` but none where `Counter` is a better fit. I try to get used to it, but I rarely get to use it at all.

Comment: @mgilson great, how did you learn this? Do you study all python modules? Or you learn by asking others?

Comment: @jamylak -- My main reason for not using `Counter` for things like this is backward compatability.

Comment: @alwbtc -- Honestly I learned by answering questions on SO.  There are sets of similar problems which usually take similar tools to solve them.  After a while, you start to learn which tools are appropriate for which type of question.  Then you start answering the questions and before you know it, you have almost 15k reputation :-)

Comment: @jamylak -- Although if I really wanted to be backwards compatible, I suppose I could fall back on `dict.setdefault` ;^) ...

Comment: @mgilson Most people use >= 2.6 nowadays I believe.

Comment: @jamylak -- I'm still using 2.6 most of the time (although that is mainly because I'm too lazy to reinstall all my packages for my 2.7 and 3.2 implementations). -- I even have a standby `odict` module which all of my scripts use to import `OrderedDict` if `collections.OrderedDict` isn't found ...

Comment: @mgilson Yea I meant to write >= my bad

Comment: @jamylak -- 2.6 doesn't have `OrderedDict` or `Counter` :-(.

Comment: @mgilson well I was replying to your `setdefault`, and 2.6 does have `defaultdict`

Comment: @jamylak -- Ahh, I understand now.  I didn't realize what your comment was in response to :).

Answer (score 6):

```
for k, v in sorted(collections.Counter(len(i) for i in list_of_lists).iteritems()):
    print 'number of lists with %s elements : %s' % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> seq = [[1,2], [1,2,4], [1,2,3,4], [4,5,6], [1,9], [1,2,4]]
>>> for k, v in Counter(map(len, seq)).most_common():
        print 'number of lists with {0} elements: {1}'.format(k, v)


number of lists with 3 elements: 3
number of lists with 2 elements: 2
number of lists with 4 elements: 1
```

Comment: (+1) for `Counter.most_common()`

Comment: @mgilson I was just about to change it but I guess i'll just leave this with most_common for the option.

Comment: I like that it demonstrates how this usage is superior to that of my `defaultdict` -- mainly that `Counters` have methods which are nice for working with counts.